# iOS iphone decompress spanned (multi-volume) .7z or .zip archives

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, zip, 7zip

I need to extract spanned (multi-volume) .7z or .zip archives in the Documents directory within my app. I tried with both libraries SSZipArchive (mini zip) and lzmaSDK but with no luck. Do these two libraries do the job? Otherwise, are there any other libraries to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used SSZipArchave before i only used ZLib. you can try it if your librarie don't work
I recomend Zlib i used it in my projects and it works great  here is a tutorial to get started [tutorial](http://www.clintharris.net/2009/how-to-gzip-data-in-memory-using-objective-c/)